# File creation error, something wrong with bin, from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, union

I've been trying to use the Union tool on a layer of building polygons, with a layer of output area polygons. The building layer has the largest number of features I've used so far, 106716, if that's relevant.

Yesterday, QGIS was just freezing up trying to do the Union, and I ended up cancelling it with a view to giving it loads of time today.

However today I've been getting an error that reads:

> No output created. File creation error:  creation of layer failed (OGR
>   error:Failed to open Shapefile `G:/New folder\Test.shp'.)

Can anyone help me resolve this new error?

Comment: Perhaps check if both layers do not have geometric errors? You can try running the **Geometry Checker** plugin or the **Check validity** tool from the _Processing Toolbox_. Have you also tried running the **Union** tool and saving the output as a **temporary file** instead?

Comment: I checked both layers using Vectors->Geometry->Check Validity, and they both reported 0 errors. Trying to figure out how to specify a temporary file, to try the other thing you suggest.

Comment: Always good when there's 0 errors :). When you run the **Union** tool, just don't specify a path for the output.

Comment: It is demanding a place to save the output, should I update to the latest version? I'm using 2.14.3.

Comment: You can try the tool from the _Processing Toolbox_, there you do not need to specify a path. I'm guessing you were using it from `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union...`.

Comment: Update! Everything's now going fine, this error was probably due to my USB getting all full up with QGIS junk. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working! You should post your last comment as an **answer** as you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this error was due to the memory stick I was using being full up, this meant it didn't have the memory to make any of the temporary files it might need to to run the Union tool.